# GWT persistent URLs

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, gwt-activities, gwt-places

I have a web-app built with GWT, Request Factory and Places/Activities. I'm curious whether history tokens I use are persistent or not. The task is basically just about having URLs that define exact places of my web-app (read as - "files/folders structure"). So, what I need is urls like `http://localhost/MyModule.html#uirwcynoerictyeroituwcyoi` that would still cause the same data to be displayed even a year later. Does history token guarantee that for some particular `Place` it would be always the same?

If no, what is solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each Place you can write your own PlaceTokenizer. So if you don`t change your PlaceTokenizer (or write them to handle legacy places), you can use the same urls as long as you like.

Take a look here: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#Places